# Angular 5 execute function after the page activate services

Tags: angular, firebase, angular5, angular-services

I have multiple services and pages in my Angular Project.

```
Pages:
1) Login
2) Dashboard
3) Order List

Services:
1) UserService
2) OrderService
```

The proper process to access OrderListPage is:

1) Login - `userServices` is initialized

2) system redirect user to Dashboard - `OrderService` is initialized before calling function inside

3) user go to Order List - function inside `OrderService` is ready to be executed for the function from `OrderList > ngOnInit()`

I have a problem is, if user is direct enter to the `http://localhost:4200/orderList` page without going through Process 1 & 2, the `OrderService` is not initialized yet, so when calling the function in `ngOnInit()` from `OrderListPage`, it will hit error `"Cannot read property 'child' of undefined"`.

My `order.service.ts`:

```
currentUser
  iwoRef

  constructor() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.currentUser = user;
        this.iwoRef = firebase.database().ref(`/iwo`);
        console.log('order services loaded')
      }
      else{
        return false
      }
    });
   }

   getIwo(iwo){
     return this.iwoRef.child('stock')
   }
```

My `order-list.component.ts`:

```
constructor(private orderService: OrderService) {  }

ngOnInit() {
  this.orderService.getIwo().on('value',snap>{
    console.log(snap.val())
  })
}
```

My Error sequence display in chrome console:

```
> Cannot read property 'child' of undefined --order.service.ts
> order services loaded --order.service.ts
```

If the user go through the Process 1, 2, 3 then will not have above issue, i suspect is because the orderService has been fully initialized in DashboardPage.

I did try to use other Angular Life Cycle function in Order List Page to execute the `this.orderService.getIwo()` but it didn't work as expected :

ngDoCheck, ngAfterContentInit, ngAfterContentChecked, ngAfterViewInit, ngAfterViewChecked

Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to initialize iwoRef

```
this.iwoRef = firebase.database().ref(`/iwo`);
```

On Authentication change?

If not, then move it outside the

```
onAuthStateChanged
```

And it would be initialized without authentication change.

Comment: i put `iwoRef` in the onAuthStateChanged because i want to make sure the user has login session first, then only can access to DB. if remove that then it might expose in security risk right?

Comment: You could use a Router/Authentication Guard which is a service that prevents users from directly entering '/orderList' URI if they are not authenticated. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxLI9_ub6PM

Comment: same thing will still happen if user direct go to OrderListPage instead of go to dashboard page first (user login already then refresh page)..

Comment: Then initialize iwoRef on the constructor of the order service, and check for authentication on the 'order-list.component.ts' before calling this.orderService.getIwo()